# Print SQLAlchemy object returned by group by and count

Tags: flask, orm, sqlalchemy

I have table where I have student information, Now I want to know the number of male and female students. Using plain SQL I can get using this

```
select student_gender, count(student_gender) from student_registration group by student_gender;
```

After small searching, I found following equivalence in SQLAlchemy

```
gender = db.session.query(Student_Registration.student_gender, \
                        func.count(Student_Registration.student_gender))\
    .group_by(Student_Registration.student_gender).all()
```

Now I want to print the desired output. using

```
for b in gender:
    print(b.student_gender)
```

How to print the count ? I tried b.count but it shows

```
Female <built-in method count of result object at 0x7fac60f21240>
Male <built-in method count of result object at 0x7fac60f21288>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've created the query, now you have to execute it and retrieve the results (yes, it confused me when I first started, too). To do that, take what you have and add the following...

Assuming you don't already have a connection to the DB (which you might actually have already - substitute the right parameters for your connection - DB connect string, uid, pw...)...

```
qry_engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://uid:pw@localhost:3306/charset=utf8mb4',
                           pool_recycle=3600, echo=False)
```

Then add something like the following

```
rslt = qry_engine.execute(gender).fetchall()
for rslt_row in rslt:
    print(str(rslt_row))
```

I haven't actually run these commands so I may have screwed up the syntax a little but the interpreter should tell you where I've made mistakes (let me know and I'll revise my answer). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [label](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.label)

```
gender = db.session.query(Student_Registration.student_gender, \
                        func.count(Student_Registration.student_gender).label('count'))\
    .group_by(Student_Registration.student_gender).all()

for b in gender:
    print(b.student_gender, b.count)
```